# Проблема с Upsert при использовании mgo

Tags: golang, mongodb

Подскажите пожалуйста, кто сталкивался с этим при работе с монгой через mgo.
Мне надо обновить документ, при его отсутствии вставить новый, юзаю Upsert

```
entry := models.Example{
    ID:           bson.NewObjectId(),
    UserID:       userID,
    SessionID:    sessionID,
    Created:      created,
  }

query := bson.M{
  "$set": entry,
}

_, err = mongo.C(mongodb.ExampleCollection).Upsert(bson.M{
  "user_id":      userID,
  "session_id":   sessionID,
}, query)
```

Так оно вставляет документ, а при апдейте ломается (&mgo.LastError{Err:"Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'", ...}), если убрать ранее сгенерированный ID, то он не может вставить его без ID.

Прочитал еще про $setOnInsert, но он видимо так на ID не работает:

```
query := bson.M{
  "$setOnInsert": bson.M{
    "_id": bson.NewObjectId(),
  },
  "$set": entry,
}
```

Comment: не могли бы показать `models.Example`? интересно какой тег стоит для ID

Comment: да, вы правы, стоит `json:"id" bson:"_id"`, надо же было еще поставить "omitempty"?

Comment: нет. вы не можете ставить `bson:"_id"`, замените на `bson:"id"`. но внутри фильтра нужно указать `bson.M{"_id": myObj.ID},`

Comment: я добавил omitempty, это решило проблему, можете оформить как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_id` генерируется автоматически. Он же является неким первичным ключом.

Ваша схема в коде должна содержать поле с тэгом `id`, тогда монго поймет, что нужно использовать его как ObjectID. Запрещается использовать `_id`, потому что он создается автоматически.

замените `myfield json:"id" bson:"_id"` на `myfield json:"id" bson:"id"`

Comment: либо добавить "omitempty" к bson тегу